# Как передать класс тегу body, который находится в get_header? wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Возникла такая задача:
Есть файл header.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <!-- Убрал неважное-->
    <? wp_head()?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class()?>>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <header class="header">
        <!-- Некоторый код-->
        </header>
```

И файл: page.php

```html
<?php get_header();?>
<!-- Какой-то контент -->
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Проблема в том, что на page.php `<header>` стилизуется по особенному и стили выглядят так:

```css
.pade .header {
    /*Какие-то стили*/
}
```

Причем `<body class="page">`
Подскажите, как можно исправить данную проблему? Чтобы либо хедер стилизовался на определенной странице, либо каким-то образом у `<body>` появлялся нужный класс. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну класс добавляет вот этот код

```
<?php body_class()?>
```

Чтобы добавить свой класс для боди нужно использовать фильтры

> Классы можно добавить с применением условий. Добавим класс только для
>   постоянных страниц (is_page()). Для этого воспользуемся фильтром
>   body_class. Код нужно вставить в файл темы function.php:
>
> ```
> add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
> function my_class_names( $classes ) {
>   // добавим класс 'class-name' в массив классов $classes
>   if( is_page() )
>       $classes[] = 'it_is_page';
>
>   return $classes;
> }
> ```

Или просто добавить произвольный класс для всех страниц

```
<body <?php body_class('class-name'); ?>>
```

https://wp-kama.ru/function/body_class

Comment: Спасибо большое!