# Как изменить содержимое header для одной страницы

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал дочернюю тему, требуется что-бы только в странице `single.php` отображалась картинка на шапке.

Вопрос не в то как сделать картинку в шапке а как изменить шапку только для одной страницы, не используя костылей типа замен `get_header()` на код шапки.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756733/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83-body-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-get-header-wordpress/756741#756741

Вот это не оно?

Comment: дело в том что мне не только класс нужно добавить а еще и html код

Comment: А вот это? https://wp-kama.ru/id_89/uslovnyie-tegi-v-wordpress-i-vse-chto-s-nimi-svyazano.html

Comment: Это то что нужно! можете написать в качестве ответа!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить условие:

```
<?php
if( is_single() ){
    //Тут код, который выполнится только если страница - это страница отдельной записи
}
?>
```

[Источник (с полным списком условных тегов)](https://wp-kama.ru/id_89/uslovnyie-tegi-v-wordpress-i-vse-chto-s-nimi-svyazano.html)

Answer (score 0):

Создать файл `header-example.php`.
В шаблоне `single.php` прописать `get_header('example');`

После этого на странице `single.php` будет отображаться header-example.

Подробнее в кодексе [Теги шаблонов/get header](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2/get_header)